# Protecting licensing implementation in C++

Tags: licensing

What ways are there to protect licensing enforcement mechanisms in C/C++?

I know of:

- Using macros (but that make the code difficult to maintain)
- Linking statically
- Obfuscating symbol names

Other methods I am not sure about:

- Using C++ templates
- Using inline functions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to keep your code as clean as possible and rely on a third party tool to protect your code.
 google for "c++ obfuscator" to find such tools.